# Memory leak for nhibernate and fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, task-parallel-library, castle-windsor

I have windows service that is basically reading messages from customer and we do process and sends them over HTTP/TCP/File etc. Service is written in C#, for database interaction I use NHibernate and TPL task.

For every batch of message service reads and inserts into SQL server database in separate TPL Task and same messages is then fetched from database in another TPL task we send them over HTTP/TCP/File after processing, and we also save this records into database using NHibernate ISession.

piece of code is below

```
public Func<ISession> GetSession { get; set; }

[Transaction]
public string SaveInMessage(ISession session, string message)
{
    try
    {
        using (var session = GetSession()){
            session.Transaction.Begin();
            var inMessage = new InMessage();
            var task = new Task(()=> InsertToDatabase(session, inMessage));
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        session.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}

public void InsertToDatabase(ISession session, InMessage inMessage){
    session.SaveOrUpdate(inMessage);
}

[Transaction]
public bool SaveOutMessage()
{    
    try
    {
        using (var session = GetSession()){
            session.Transaction.Begin();
            var inMessage = session.Load<InMessage>();
            var outMessage = new OutMessage();
            var task = new Task(()=> ConvertMessage(outMessage, inMessage, session));
            var task = new Task(()=> SendMessage(outMessage, session, outProtocol));
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        session.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}

public void ConvertMessage(OutMessage outMessage, ISession session, Http url)
{
    conversion logic goes here;
}

public void SendMessage(OutMessage outMessage,ISession session,Protocol outProtocol)
{
    Sending message logic goes here;
    session.SaveOrUpdate(inMessage);
}
```

So, in above I have used Castle.Windsor for IoC and Transaction attribute used in these two methods are from same. 
I am keep getting below AggregateException along with OutOfMemoryException within NHibernate and TPL.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.String.ConcatArray(String[] values, Int32 totalLength)
at System.String.Concat(Object[] args)
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.CascadeOnFlush(IEventSource session, IEntityPersister persister, Object key, Object anything)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
at Service.ProcessMessage(Message message, ISession session) in C:\Project\Service\ProcessMessage.cs:line 247
at Service.ProcessMessage.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<SendMessages>b__0(Task c) in C:\Project\Service\ProcessMessage.cs:line 74
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Service.ProcessMessage.SendMessages(CancellationToken cancelToken) in C:\Project\Service\ProcessMessage.cs:line 73
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.String.ConcatArray(String[] values, Int32 totalLength)
at System.String.Concat(Object[] args)
at NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.CascadeOnFlush(IEventSource session, IEntityPersister persister, Object key, Object anything)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
at Service.ProcessMessage.Process(Message message, ISession session) in C:\Project\Service\ProcessMessage.cs:line 247
at Service.ProcessMessage.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<SendMessages>b__0(Task c) in C:\Project\Service\ProcessMessage.cs:line 74
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
LogExtension.Event => LogExtension.Event => LogExtension.LogEvent
```

Above error is coming after 4-5 hours after windows service is started.

Any hint or help is appreciated.

- .Net framework version I use is 4.5
- NHibernate version is 4.0.4.4000
- Castle.Windsor version is 3.3.0
- FluentNhibernate version is 1.3.0.733
- Castle.Facilities.NHibernate version is 0.7.1.23602
- Castle.Facilities.AutoTx version is 3.2.207.2207
- Castle.Core version is 3.3.3

Comment: This does not mean that there is a memory leak within NHibernate or TPL, just that the out of memory happens when NHibernate or TPL want to create some new objects. Memory profile your application using the memory snapshot feature (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) to find the exact objects staying in memory.

Comment: yes you may be right I ran DotMemory and it seems that DotMemory shows more memory used by NHibernate 195,497,059 retained bytes, 93,234,484 bytes, and 2,431,471 objects in count.
And garbage collector at generation 2 is growing without a clean

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your logic for `GetSession()`, but I get the impression you are re-using the same session for all of the messages. Sessions are supposed to be short lived. Keeping a single session open will result in the first level cache growing to the point where you get performance degradation and eventually run out of memory.

Comment: first line of my code at which it is declared of type Func<ISession> which is of type NHibernate.